# How to force recompilation of classes that call macros?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-macros

I have some code that depends on a macro call. In my case the macro-code iterates over fields of a type T and returns their name recursively:

```
object Foo{
  val bar:List[String] = MyMacroClass.fieldNames[Bar]
}
```

The `Bar` and `MyMacro` each are defined in separate independent sub-projects.

Now when I do changes to Bar, like adding or removing fields, the list will not reflect the changes if I don't manually clean and recompile.

Is there a way to tell sbt to recompile such cases?

*ps. similar questions were asked [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/simple-build-tool/1366fkm8r0/sbt-forcing-a-class-using-a-macro-to-recompile) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/M2QO1Ki3IyQ).*

Comment: seems to be a known issue of sbt: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1729

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dependsOn](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Multi-Project.html) in `MyMacro` to force it to recompile each time `Bar` is changed. Something like `lazy val MyMacroProject = project.dependsOn(BarProject)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The solution is not very nice for a very generic macro that should work with any type T but by chance in my case the macro sub-project already dependsOn the sub-project that contains Bar. Still it doesn't do the trick.